# How do I assign a child class to a generic field in a non-generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

In C#, I am trying to store a private generic variable in a non-generic class that is passed in through a generic method.
The generic method is supposed to take child classes that are upcast to the base class type.

Here is an example of the issue:

```
class BaseModel { }
class DerivedModel : BaseModel { }

class Data<T> where T : BaseModel { }

// Class is NOT generic
class DataConsumer
{
    // How do I set this to generic?
    private Data<BaseModel> data;

    public void Set<T>(Data<T> data) where T : BaseModel
    {
        // Compile time error: 
        // Cannot convert source type 'Generic.Data<T> 
        // to target type 'Generic.Data<Generic.BaseModel>'
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: We specifically do not want to make `DataConsumer` generic since it will have many different generic methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're trying to assign a more derived type `Data<T>` to a base type `Data<BaseModel>`, which is not allowed in generic classes.

You have two options:

1- Make `DataConsumer` generic:

```
class DataConsumer<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    private Data<T> data;

    public void Set(Data<T> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

2- OR, make `Data` an interface instead of a class and mark `T` as a *covariant* type using the `out` keyword:

```
interface IData<out T> where T : BaseModel { }

class DataConsumer
{
    private IData<BaseModel> data;

    public void Set<T>(IData<T> data) where T : BaseModel
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Read more about [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`this.data` is of type `Data<BaseModel>` while the function parameter `data` is of type `Data<T : BaseModel>`.

Your example kinda defeats the entire purpose of generics in the first place, but you can declare the `Set()` method a non-generic method, and force the client to do the cast.

```
private Data<BaseModel> data;

public void Set(Data<BaseModel> data)
{
  this.data = data;
}
```

As a side note, if you declared all entities involved to be generic, the constraint would only allow you to manipulate the objects through `BaseModel`'s contract, so I can't see how the explicit cast would be necessary.